# Asp.net GridView Control

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to display the grid view like this -(fig 1)

```
Sr.no  Class  ----Division------   Total
              A      B       C
-----------------------------------
 1.    1st    10     20       30     60
 2.    2nd    20     10       40     70
-----------------------------------
Total  30     30       70     130
```

values shown are total_no_students in Division A,B,C..

and from table i get data like this-(fig-2)

```
Class      A     B     C
 1st      10     20    30
 2nd      20     10    40
```

i created the gridview..but if i directly bind the data i get same as fig-2

how should i customize gridview so that it displays the data as fig-1

Apart from gridview if there is any other control that i can use please do suggest me
thank you

Comment: You will have to use footer template for showing the total below. And a template field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom row will require a GridView footer.

[Footer Example](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1676759)

For the column total the following example will solve your problem (check Rahul's answer)

[Row Total Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098793/gridview-column-and-row-total)

Comment: hey thanx Footer and row issue solved..but now what is happening is my columns are getting added twice first through the <Boundfield> and <template> and secondly i guess through code could u please help me how should i resolve it..also i want to display headers and then the actual column as u cam see in my question..please tell me how should i do that..

Comment: actaully i didnt knew at a time wen can mark only one answer even his answer did work...i m done with evrythin now only i am nt able to display the upperformat i.e frist division name and then below it A B and C..can u help me with that?

Comment: Cheers. These links should help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27824/Dynamic-Multiple-Row-Column-Grid-Header   and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2006/03/01/real-world-gridview-two-headed-grouping-gridviews.aspx